# How can Bing's Universal Event Tracking track "pages" in a pop-up?

Tags: bing

I have a site where a user can open a modal window containing a number of "pages" which are actually HTML replaced by AJAX (ie, there is only one real page). In order to make each screen look like a new thing to Google Analytics, each time the "next" button is pressed, I do this

```
  ga('set', 'page', pagePath);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

which works fine. I've been asked to add Bing tracking to the same application. The standard inclusion obviously only tracks the first page load. Is there an equivalent to the GA code for Bing?

The Bing documentation seems to suggest I should be using a custom event for this, like

```
window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push
({ 'ec':'Event category', 'ea':'Event action', 'el':'Event label', 'ev':'Event value' });
```

but I only seem to be able to set up a conversion goal, and it seems wrong to make every "page" a conversion goal when, strictly speaking, only the very last one is, and I need to be able track how far through the pages the user got before they gave up.